# MPI: How to concatenate sub-arrays in multiple processors into a larger single array

Tags: c, mpi

I am using MPI in C. I was able to distribute parts of an array to different processors. And the different processors did all the manipulation I wanted. Now I am at the point where I wanted to combine all the sub-arrays that are in all the processors into one big array. For example if the different processors had sub-arrrays as follows:

```
Processor 1:
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0

Processor 2:
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1

Processor 3:
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1

...
```

I want to be able to combine, or "concatenate", all the sub-arrays together. For example I would want the large array to be:

```
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1
...
```

I was trying to use MPI_Reduce but I couldn't find an operation to do what I wanted to do. Is there another MPI method I could use to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for MPI_Gather:

> > Each process (root process included) sends the contents of its send buffer to the root process. The root process receives the messages and stores them in rank order.

For documentation and examples, see [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Gather.html) and [here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Gather.html). The section 5.5 in the [MPI 2.2 Standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf) also has examples.